# how to read from CSV file while cells have multi lines

Tags: csv, newline

I have a CSV file that some cells of it have multiple line 
for example if you copy the cell content and paste it in the MS word you will get

Name : testName

Age : 30

when I read them this way

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(FileName));
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    tmpLineData = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

when the reader face the new line it will read it as a new Row !
any ideas?

Comment: Is there a real line terminator, then, to know when a line really ends (like `;` or something)? Or do you have to match the filed terminators to know if the newline exists within a cell?

Comment: If the case is that there are no real line-delimiters as I asked above, the two things that come to mind would be to read in the file character by character and keeping track of fields yourself or to use a pre-created library (there are quite a few out there) that already takes care of stuff like that for you

Comment: reading it character by character is not a good way to solve it !

Comment: I can't think of any other way to do it (and kind of wonder why you say it's not a good solution, actually) unless you have a different row terminator... Kinda curious to see what other solutions get posted...